# Use JS var value only after a button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to show which menu value was selected using JavaScript, like this:

```
<script> 
document.writeln(value);
</script>
```

Where the JS variable called `value` gets defined by jQuery when a button is clicked:

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
    var value = $('#model').val();   

});
```

The problem being that the code tries to render `value` before it has been created by the button.

I know I can show/hide a `div` based on the button click, but even if the section with `writeln` is hidden it still has the same problem. I also need to be able to change my selection, click submit, and have the value update properly.

Here's a jsFiddle illustrating the problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/f3n7uq14/4/

Comment: Please explain the downvote so that I can improve the question

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I would assume it's because this question sounds like a homework assignment, and people here don't like doing other people's homework for them.

Comment: @minboost I'm 38. It's not homework. I'm trying to get this to work as a half step to passing a value to my JSP so that I initialize the right Java program on the backend.

Comment: Well, I'm just giving you an idea why you might have gotten downvoted. I've already answered your question (feel free to accept it!).

Comment: Just to comment on the code above, the variable `value` only exists in the scope of the call back function. Even if `document.writeln` was called after the function had executed it would still give an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<span id="result"></span>
<script>
$('#submit').click(function(){
    var value = $('#model').val();
    $('#result').text(value);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. So I take it I'd be putting `result` in `writeln`. This looks right. I'm trying to get it working in jsFiddle now. I can accept your answer in 8 minutes. If you have a chance to show it in jsFiddle that would be amazing, but either way many thanks.

Comment: Your question and your fiddle don't really line up. Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/z8fL1e3f/